# Passing a String ArrayList to a method returning a double value

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on an assignment question, which im stuck at:

i extracted a text file grades.txt to an arraylist called studentgrade
i want to then using the grades ive extracted to the arraylist to  method convertgrade.

the purpose of the convert grade is the read the line of the text file and then convert the string value to points; and then adding up all the grades the summed points.

```
package Q2;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;

public class studentGPA {

private static String studentGrades[];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double gpa, points = 0;     
    //opening grades and extracting to array

    File file = new File ("Grades.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    ArrayList<String> studentlist = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                studentlist.add(inputFile.nextLine()); 
            }

/*print out student ID

    for (int index = 0; index<studentlist.size(); index++)
    {
        StudentID = (studentlist.get(index)).split(" ",11);
        System.out.println("studentID:" + index + ": " + StudentID[0]);

    } 
    System.out.println(); */



            studentGrades = null;

    for (int index = 0; index<studentlist.size(); index++)
    {
        String data[] = studentlist.get(index).split(" ");
       for (int index_grade = 0 ; index_grade < 8;)
        {
          studentGrades[index_grade] = data[index_grade+3];
      }
        System.out.println(convertGrade(studentGrades));

    }

    //testing purposes
    /*for (int index = 0; index<studentlist.size(); index++)
    {
        StudentGrade = (studentlist.get(index)).split(" ",11);


        System.out.println("studentID:" + index + ": " + StudentGrade[3] +  StudentGrade[4] + 
                StudentGrade[5] + StudentGrade[6] + StudentGrade[7] + StudentGrade[8] + StudentGrade[9] );
    }*/




    //answer should be 46 but im getting 14


}

 public static double convertGrade(String studentgrade[]) {
      double points = 0;

      for (int index = 3; index<studentgrade.length; index++)
      {
      if (studentgrade[index].contains("H"))
          points = 7;
      else if (studentgrade[index].contains("D"))
          points = 6;
      else if (studentgrade[index].contains("C"))
          points = 5;
      else if (studentgrade[index].contains("P"))
          points = 4;
      else if (studentgrade[index].contains("F"))
          points = 0;
      points = points + points;
      }
      return points;
   }


}
```

- 57363 Joy Ryder D D C P H H C D            ==== 6 + 6 +5 +4 + 7 + 7 +5 + 6  = 46
- 72992 Laura Norder H H H D D H H H

  - 71258 Eileen Over C F C D C C C P

EDIT:

Comment: I see a method that accepts an `String[]` and returns `double`, but not a method that accepts `List<String>` and returns `double`.  Outside of that, could you try and isolate specifically where the points are being put into your data structure?  It's a bit tough to tell.

Comment: @Makoto It seems every element of the ArrayList is split on spaces, which gives ``String[]``.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation; i want to return a double value so i can then write that double value to a new textfile called GPA.text which i havn't implemented yet; the purpose of this question is to extract the grades and convert them to points so i can then calculate the final GPA

Comment: where is your txt file? its gone..i cannot answer your question if you delete it

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I've resposted it sorry

Answer (score 0):

you must do it like this :

```
System.out.println(convertGrade(StudentGrade));
```

**EDIT**

```
for (int index = 0; index<studentlist.size(); index++)
{
    String data[] = studentlist.get(index).split(" ");
    for (int index_grade = 0 ; index_grade < 8)
    {
       StudentGrade[index_grade] = data[index_grade+3];
    }
    System.out.println(convertGrade(StudentGrade));
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. The result of the ``convertGrade`` method is never used anywhere. Be sure to put this within the ``for`` loop. Also, you might want to skip over the first 3 elements of the array in the ``convertGrade`` method, since the name might also contain an H, D, C, P or F.

Comment: Hi Randyka, i've implemented what you've suggested and now the method outputs a result; thanks!... but the issue is its outputting the wrong result its outputting 8 when the first line should output 46.... Ghostkeeper: how do i skip? must i use trim?

Comment: to skip, just add +3 to index

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira just used your code , do i place this in the main or in the method?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira i used your code but i got no output

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira i keep getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Q2.studentGPA.main(studentGPA.java:46) Referring to StudentGrades[] = null;

Comment: sorry, change your studentGrades = null to studentGrades = new String[studentlist.size()];

Comment: Thanks. ill try this tonight and post back to you when ive code it :)